# Get all the javascript file name and its contents in python perfectly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scan some websites and would like to get all the java script files names and content.I tried python requests with BeautifulSoup but wasn't able to get the scripts details and contents.am I missing something ?

I have been trying lot of methods to find but I felt like stumbling in the dark.
This is the code I am trying

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Comment: I tried requests with beautifulSoup.I cant give specific class name for scanning because it all varies from site to site.Identifying files as javascript itself is my requirment.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What's your code? Could you [edit] your question and add a [mcve] please? Do you mean that get `src` from all the `<script>` tags from a page? If so, have you tried `[i.get('src') for i in soup.find_all('src')]`?

Comment: @KevinGuan I tried lot of methods I dont remember at all and not worthy to write here.I edited the questsion and wrote until i believe its clear about my path

Comment: @AravindKrishna: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Hmm...as I asked: What's the expected output then? Are you trying to get all the JavaScript code from that page?

Comment: @KevinGuan all the javascript files names and contents. for example like jquery script is used or not.yes all the javascript code as well as the names of javascript file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all the linked JavaScript code use the below code:

```
l = [i.get('src') for i in soup.find_all('script') if i.get('src')]
```

- `soup.find_all('script')` returns a list of all the `<script>` tags in the page.
- A [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/) is used here to loop over all the elements in the list which returned by `soup.find_all('script')`.
- `i` is a *dict like* object, use `.get('src')` to check if it has `src` attribute. If not, ignore it. Otherwise, put it into a list (which's called `l` in the example).

The output, in this case looks like below:

```
['http://adserver.adtech.de/addyn/3.0/1602/5506153/0/6490/ADTECH;loc=700;target=_blank;grp=[group]',
 'http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js',
 'http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js',
 'http://js.genieessp.com/t/057/794/a1057794.js',
 'http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5620689&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]',
 'http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5531763',
 'http://advs.adgorithms.com/ttj?id=3279193&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]',
 'http://xp2.zedo.com/jsc/xp2/fo.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/mnmads.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/jquery.cookie.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/swanalekha-ml.js',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/marunadan.js?r=1875',
 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/taboola_home.js',
 'http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js']
```

---

My code missed some links because they're not in the HTML source actually.

You can see them in the console:

[image: Chrome console]

But they're not in the source:

[image: HTML source]

Usually, that's because these links were generated by JavaScript. And the `requests` module doesn't run any JavaScript in the page like *a real browser* - it only send a request to get the HTML source.

If you also need them, you have to use another module to run the JavaScript in that page, and you can see these links then. For that, I'd suggest use [**selenium**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) - which runs *a real browser* so it can runs JavaScript in the page.

For example (make sure that you have already installed selenium and a web driver for it):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # use Chrome driver for example
driver.get('http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
l = [i.get('src') for i in soup.find_all('script') if i.get('src')]

__import__('pprint').pprint(l)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I think now my question makes complete sense."javascript file name and its contents in python _**perfectly**_". perfect  should be renamed as to get async scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a select with `script[src]` which will only find script tags with a src, you don't need to call .get multiple times:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

src = [sc["src"] for sc in  soup.select("script[src]")]
```

You can also specify `src=True` with find_all to do the same:

```
src = [sc["src"] for sc in soup.find_all("script",src=True)]
```

Which will both give you the same output:

```
['http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js', 'http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js', 'http://js.genieessp.com/t/052/954/a1052954.js', '//s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/tms-t/marunadanmalayali-7219.js', 'http://advs.adgorithms.com/ttj?id=3279193&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]', 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/mnmcombined1.min.js', 'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/mnmcombined2.min.js']
```

Also if you use selenium, you can use it with [*PhantomJs*](http://phantomjs.org/) for headless browsing, you don't need beautufulSoup at all if you use selenium, you can use the same css selector directly in selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/')

src = [sc.get_attribute("src") for sc in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("script[src]")]
print(src)
```

Which gives you all the links:

```
u'https://pixel.yabidos.com/fltiu.js?qid=836373f5137373f5131353&cid=511&p=165&s=http%3a%2f%2fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2f&x=admeta&nci=&adtg=96331&nai=', u'http://gum.criteo.com/sync?c=72&r=2&j=TRC.getRTUS', u'http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js', u'http://cdn.taboola.com/libtrc/impl.201-1-RELEASE.js', u'http://p165.atemda.com/JSAdservingMP.ashx?pc=1&pbId=165&clk=&exm=&jsv=1.84&tsv=2.26&cts=1459160775430&arp=0&fl=0&vitp=0&vit=&jscb=&url=&fp=0;400;300;20&oid=&exr=&mraid=&apid=&apbndl=&mpp=0&uid=&cb=54613943&pId0=64056124&rank0=1&gid0=64056124:1c59ac&pp0=&clk0=[External%20click-tracking%20goes%20here%20(NOT%20URL-encoded)]&rpos0=0&ecpm0=&ntv0=&ntl0=&adsid0=', u'http://cdn.taboola.com/libtrc/marunadanaalayali-network/loader.js', u'http://s.atemda.com/Admeta.js', u'http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', u'http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js', u'http://tags.expo9.exponential.com/tags/MarunadanMalayalicom/ROS/tags.js', u'http://js.genieessp.com/t/052/954/a1052954.js', u'http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/tms-t/marunadanmalayali-7219.js', u'http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js', u'http://z1.zedo.com/asw/fm/1185/7219/9/fm.js?c=7219&a=0&f=&n=1185&r=1&d=9&adm=&q=&$=&s=1936&l=%5BINSERT_CLICK_TRACKER_MACRO%5D&ct=&z=0.025054786819964647&tt=0&tz=0&pu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2F&ru=&pi=1459160768626&ce=UTF-8&zpu=www.marunadanmalayali.com____1_&tpu=', u'http://cas.criteo.com/delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=308686&nodis=1&cb=38688817829&exclude=undefined&charset=UTF-8&loc=http%3A//www.marunadanmalayali.com/', u'http://ads.pubmatic.com/AdServer/js/showad.js', u'http://showads.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdServerServlet?pubId=135167&siteId=135548&adId=600924&kadwidth=300&kadheight=250&SAVersion=2&js=1&kdntuid=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2F&inIframe=0&kadpageurl=marunadanmalayali.com&operId=3&kltstamp=2016-3-28%2011%3A26%3A13&timezone=1&screenResolution=1024x768&ranreq=0.8869257988408208&pmUniAdId=0&adVisibility=2&adPosition=999x664', u'http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js', u'http://z1.zedo.com/asw/fm/1185/7213/9/fm.js?c=7213&a=0&f=&n=1185&r=1&d=9&adm=&q=&$=&s=1948&l=%5BINSERT_CLICK_TRACKER_MACRO%5D&ct=&z=0.08655649935826659&tt=0&tz=0&pu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2F&ru=&pi=1459160768626&ce=UTF-8&zpu=www.marunadanmalayali.com____1_&tpu=', u'http://advs.adgorithms.com/ttj?id=3279193&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]', u'http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?ttjb=1&bdc=1459160761&bdh=ZllBLkzcj2dGDVPeS0Sw_OTWjgQ.&tpuids=eyJ0cHVpZHMiOlt7InByb3ZpZGVyIjoiY3JpdGVvIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6Il9KRC1PUmhLX3hLczd1cUJhbjlwLU1KQ2VZbDQ2VVUxIn1dfQ==&view_iv=0&view_pos=664,2096&view_ws=400,300&view_vs=3&bdref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2F&bdtop=true&bdifs=0&bstk=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2F&&id=3279193&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]&pubclick=[INSERT_CLICK_TAG]', u'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/mnmcombined1.min.js', u'http://www.marunadanmalayali.com/js/mnmcombined2.min.js', u'http://pixel.yabidos.com/iftfl.js?ver=1.4.2&qid=836373f5137373f5131353&cid=511&p=165&s=http%3a%2f%2fwww.marunadanmalayali.com%2f&x=admeta&adtg=96331&nci=&nai=&nsi=&cstm1=&cstm2=&cstm3=&kqt=&xc=&test=&od1=&od2=&co=0&tps=34&rnd=3m17uji8ftbf']
```